# Laravel Class App\Http\Controllers\SessionsController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Осуществляю регистрацию пользователя. Регистрация работает,а вот выход из нее выдает ошибку .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

список роутов

```
Route::get('/register','RegistrationController@create');
Route::post('/register','RegistrationController@store');

Route::get('/login','SessionsController@create');
Route::get('/logout','SessionsController@destroy');
```

RegistrationController
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
SessionController
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если перевести то пишет что SessionController не существует. 
Видел похожую проблему писали что нужно подправить namespace. Если это так , может кто-то знает что именно нужно.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan clear:cache`, `php artisan clear-compiled` ,попробуй

Comment: Пробовал не то.

Comment: у тебя названия разные!!!! Sessions и Session

Comment: @Orange_shadow  Спасибо,  это оно !!!